# How to get row data from CSV File

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, csv

I am reading data from a CSV file and and my goal is to get only selected columns however so far I am only able to loop to get the headers alone. Can someone assist me to loop until I get the rows?.

Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub btn_import_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_import.Click
    Call csvmanagement()

End Sub
Structure systemstructure

    Dim cGroupName As String
    Dim cTransactDate As String
    Dim cRow_ID As String
    Dim cFullName As String
End Structure


Public Sub csvmanagement()

    Dim systemspecs As New systemstructure
    'Dim raw, column As Integer
    Using csvparser As New FileIO.TextFieldParser _
    ("C:\Users\Eranji\Downloads\new.csv")

        Dim csvalue As String()

        csvparser.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        csvparser.Delimiters = New String() {","}

        csvalue = csvparser.ReadFields()

        systemspecs.cGroupName = csvalue(0)
        systemspecs.cTransactDate = csvalue(1)
        systemspecs.cRow_ID = csvalue(2)
        systemspecs.cFullName = csvalue(2)

        While Not csvparser.EndOfData

        End While
        csvalue = csvparser.ReadFields()

        End

        ListBox1.Items.Add(systemspecs.cFullName & Chr(9) & systemspecs.cGroupName & Chr(9) & systemspecs.cRow_ID & systemspecs.cTransactDate)
    End Using

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 4):

You only ReadFields once
ReadFields is one line
You need to loop to end

```
While Not MyReader.EndOfData
   csvalue = csvparser.ReadFields()
   ...
End
```

[TextFieldParser.ReadFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.readfields.aspx)

Comment: Hello Blam I need to get both the columns and the rows...,will that be enough..,

Comment: Hello C-Pound Guru I need to get both the columns and the rows...,will that be enough..,

Comment: You are doing NOTHING in the loop.   How can you expect that loop to process anything if you are doing nothing in the loop?